# Leafletjs setOpacity on L.GridLayer

Tags: javascript, leaflet

How do I change dynamically opacity level of Leafletjs L.GridLayer?

This works for normal layers, eg:

```
<input id="slide" type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="0.5" onchange="updateOpacity(this.value)">


var layer =L.tileLayer(url).addTo(map);

function updateOpacity(value) {
   layer.setOpacity(value);
}
```

But the same approach doesn't work with a canvas layer defined as, eg:

```
L.GridLayer.CanvasCircles = L.GridLayer.extend({... or
CanvasCircles = L.GridLayer.extend({...


CanvasCircles = L.GridLayer.extend({
        createTile: function (coords) {
            var tile = document.createElement('canvas');
            var tileSize = this.getTileSize();
            tile.setAttribute('width', tileSize.x);
            tile.setAttribute('height', tileSize.y);

            var ctx = tile.getContext('2d');

            // Draw whatever is needed in the canvas context
            // For example, circles which get bigger as we zoom in
            ctx.arc(tileSize.x/2, tileSize.x/2, 4 + coords.z*4, 0, 2*Math.PI, false);
            ctx.fill();

            return tile;
        }
    });

    canvasCircles = function(opts) {

       return new CanvasCircles(opts);

    };

   map.addLayer( canvasCircles() );
```

Comment: Works for me. See https://plnkr.co/edit/i3NvpO8RHiAbuCvTNsci?p=preview

Comment: I see you added a few bits: var canvasCirclesLayer = canvasCircles(); and then add the layer to the map with map.addLayer( canvasCirclesLayer ); But slider with this function still does not change the opacity: function updateOpacity(value) {canvasCirclesLayer.setOpacity(value);}  Any further clues?

Comment: Ok, it does work if I use your code entirely (ie add the function to your code). But it doesn't in mine. Javascript mystery :-) Thanks!

Comment: Well, your original code doesn't have any calls to `setOpacity()`. Please provide an example with a slider that other people can run (incidentally, please take a bit of time to read through https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution, thanks to [IvanSanchez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4768502/ivansanchez), is to reference the function initiating the layer to a variable. Then that variable can be referenced in the opacity change function. Expanding on the original Leafletjs example (http://leafletjs.com/examples/extending/extending-2-layers.html), the full code is as follows:

HTML:

```
<input id="slide" type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="1" onchange="updateOpacity(this.value)">
```

JS:

```
CanvasCircles = L.GridLayer.extend({
  createTile: function(coords) {
    var tile = document.createElement('canvas');
    var tileSize = this.getTileSize();
    tile.setAttribute('width', tileSize.x);
    tile.setAttribute('height', tileSize.y);

    var ctx = tile.getContext('2d');

    // Draw whatever is needed in the canvas context
    // For example, circles which get bigger as we zoom in
    ctx.arc(tileSize.x / 2, tileSize.x / 2, 4 + coords.z * 4, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    ctx.fill();

    return tile;
  }
});

canvasCircles = function(opts) {
  return new CanvasCircles(opts);
};

var canvasCirclesLayer = canvasCircles(); //This is what makes the difference!

map.addLayer(canvasCirclesLayer);


function updateOpacity(value) {

canvasCirclesLayer.setOpacity(value);

}
```